# Trying to calculate percentage but it is showing zero in every row

Tags: sql

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEd67.png) is a screenshot of some data. I'm trying to calculate the `DeathPercentage` with the following script.

```
SELECT 
    location, date, total_cases,total_deaths, 
    ((total_deaths / total_cases) * 100) AS DeathPercentage
FROM 
    CovidDeaths_csv cdc
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`total_deaths` and `total_cases` are integers, and you are calculating the integer ratio. As deaths < cases, deaths/cases = 0. Try `((total_deaths*1.0/total_cases)*100)`.